# Can't see option file for serial devices

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (in ssh). My kernel version is:

```
root@sintrones-abox:/# uname -r
5.4.0-122-generic
```

I need to modify the file `linux-x.x.x/drivers/usb/serial/option.c` in order to install a particular driver for a 5G module. Anyway, this is the `/usr/src` folder:

```
root@sintrones-abox:/# ls /usr/src
backport-iwlwifi-8324  linux-headers-5.4.0-122-generic  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-122
```

I found the folder `drivers/usb/serial` into the path:

```
/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-122/drivers/usb/serial/
```

Anyway, in this folder there is no option.c file. These are the files:

```
root@sintrones-abox:/# ls /usr/src/linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-122/drivers/usb/serial/
ezusb_convert.pl  Kconfig  Makefile  Makefile-keyspan_pda_fw
```

How can I find the option.c? I tried `make`, but:

```
root@sintrones-abox:/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-122/drivers/usb/serial# make
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```